# Xhr params failing but question mark is passing - why?

Tags: javascript

Working:

```
      xhr.open('POST', "employee.jsp?empId=123", true);

      xhr.send();
```

Not-working:

```
      xhr.send(params); where params is 'empId=123'
```

Not sure what is the different between the two.

Can someone please explain.

Thanks.

Comment: That means that the JSP is getting its parameters from the query string, not post data.

Comment: yes, but @Barmar why it is getting from query string instead of post data? i am sending via params only...xhr.send(params)

Comment: Because that's the way the server code is written. The programmer can choose whether to get its parameters from the query string or the request body, they chose the query string.